# Disable select, allow copy/paste

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome

I'm building an app which overrides standard selecting behaviour and allow copying and pasting elements. The problem is that if I disable selecting, copy events are also gone.

I tried using

```
onselectstart="return false;"
```

and

```
.no-select {     
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;  
}
```

and it works, but it also disable copy event.

I also tried adding `.no-select` attribute only for these parts which contain text, but it is hard to maintain and does not work well - sometimes copy events are blocked and I cannot control it.

How can I disable select, but enable copy/paste proper way?

---

**Edit:**

- I do not want to copy text, but my own json structures. Copying is handled in `onCopy` handler.
- I need to subscribe to standard chrome copy events launched by chrome menu or system shortuts.

Comment: I'm wondering how you can do copy/paste without selecting text?

Comment: I handle copy in `onCopy` event

Comment: I don't want to copy text (which is standard behaviour), but my own json representation of objects

Comment: Just make small button behind that text, that signals the user to copy that text as a object without selecting it. There was also a library called clipboardjs which you can use to put things into the clipboard.

Comment: @Kyon: I cannot add any buttons, context menus and so on. I can only relay on standard copy event triggered by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

When you disabled highlighting/selecting then what you want copy? Not selected things is still nothing

> I don't want to copy text (which is standard behaviour), but my own
>   json representation of objects

Then i have 2 solutions to your problem:

1. Override context menu with function copying to clipboard ([tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-copy-to-clipboard/) and [library](https://clipboardjs.com/))

   ```js
   if (document.addEventListener) {
           document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
               alert("Write own menu with copy");
               e.preventDefault();
           }, false);
       } else {
           document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
               alert("Write own menu with copy");
               window.event.returnValue = false;
           });
       }
   ```

   ```css
   body {     
       -webkit-touch-callout: none;
       -webkit-user-select: none;
       -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
       -ms-user-select: none;
       user-select: none;  
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <body>
   Some text
   </body>
   ```
2. Add "Copy" button with function copying to clipboard ([tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-copy-to-clipboard/) and [library](https://clipboardjs.com/))
3. Bind key combination `ctrl + c` (and other like `command + c`) with function copying to clipboard ([tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-copy-to-clipboard/) and [library](https://clipboardjs.com/))
4. Use Flash or other external browser addon to provide copy to clipboard function ([not recommended](https://blog.google/products/chrome/flash-and-chrome/))

Comment: Unfortunately in my app there is no place for context menu (it is disabled, because right mouse button does something else). I also cannot also use custom key binding, because I need it to work with chrome copy/paste menu and users' system specific shortcuts.

Comment: So "Copy" button or bind key combination ctrl+c with function copying to clipboard (https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-copy-to-clipboard/). I dont see other ways

Comment: But on Mac there is `Command+c`, user also may have its own shortcuts.

Comment: So bind `Command+c` too or just add "Copy" button. If you have problem with that then you can build own fork of web browser (for example webkit https://github.com/WebKit/webkit) and modify *almost* anything what you want. Why not all? Cuz web browser is only program in OS so for full control you need to create own OS (or fork existing). For good star i can recommend `Plan9` or `InfernoOS`. If you are old fashion `FreeBSD` also can be fine. Welcome to IT dependencies world

Comment: @J.Doe This is insane. Web browser provide buttons like "copy" button in chrome menu. Is there really any way to bind to it without "forking web browser"?

Comment: @WojciechDanilo I told every solution. There is really problem to create a button (or bind key combination) with function what will create selectable invisible div, select text and then copy to clipboard? (and after maybe delete). Copy in web browser are strictly typed with highlighting/selecting (cuz you need something to copy)

Comment: @J.Doe I'm not talking it is a problem. If I create a feature, the "nice design" is to support the default, built-in components. Such component is an existing button "copy" in chrome. If there is a button buil into a webbrowser and anybody clicks on it, it should behave as copy. I think this is just "consistency" and it is a part of good design.

Comment: @J.Doe, these are nice workarounds, not the solution.

Comment: @J.Doe, selecting is what user sees is selected. Not everything is text in real life, user can also select some elements which are not text ;)

Comment: @remdezx Yes and that is what i linked in my answer (for example copy data attribute https://clipboardjs.com/) but how do you want copy by context menu something what user cant see by deafult? (it should copy html, null or super-uber-attribute-specific-only-by-webkit?)

Comment: I never wrote that I want to do it by context menu.

Comment: Chrome has copy / paste buttons in its main menu. I just need to make copy event work and disable selecting text, because it looks bad in this type of application. HTML is no longer only for websites, it is also for creating applications. There are plenty of desktop apps where you can copy, but cannot select text ;)